# Is there a way to customise the format for logging in pytest from conftest.py

Tags: python, logging, pytest, conftest

Am new to pytest and am trying to setup logging

I have the following code in my conftest.py file

```
def pytest_logger_config(logger_config):
    logger_config.add_loggers([log_fname], stdout_level=logging.INFO)
    logger_config.set_log_option_default(log_fname)
```

Another file logger.py

```
Log = logging.getLogger(log_fname)
```

on writing `Log.info("message")`

I see the log written as 
**00:16.748 inf logfile_00_00_13_10_2020.log: message**

Not sure how or where this format is defined.

Can we customise it to a format like

`log_file_format = %(levelname)s: %(asctime)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s %(message)s)`

INFO: 2020-10-13 00:00:45 (.py:<line_no>) message

Where should be the right place to define this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `pytest.ini` file:

```
[pytest]
log_format =  %(levelname)s: %(asctime)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s %(message)s)
log_date_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

You also don't need to add your own log configuration directly into test code, just enable pytest's live logging features (documented [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/logging.html#live-logs)).

Comment: Thanks wim, I had tried this as well but the output file for this prints ANSI
**[32mINFO    [0m **  
is there a way to disable that?

Comment: Use a terminal emulator that supports ANSI colors, or disable them `export PYTEST_ADDOPTS="--color=no"`

Comment: Working fine on the console.
Seeing these when content is written to a file, for allure report.

Comment: That much is out of scope of Python itself, and the behavior depends how you are writing to file, whether going through any shell pipes, etc ..